# Will the diagonal elements of transitive closure matrix of a 'graph' always be 1?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

(CAUTION- PLEASE DO NOT TAKE MY QUESTIONS VERY SERIOUSLY.

I  received a ban from asking questions,I don't know what to say really,I am just a student trying to learn,not a professional mathematician,so of course the questions could have been,well weird or useless to the mathematical community...I really did not mean any harm or anything except just trying to understand something.I really wish a feature like,telling you exactly what to do with your questions so the ban would get lifted was there.But I guess this is just hard luck and me not taking this community very seriously.I do apologize to the community,and I do understand that asking a question is a privilege not a right here.because,like to stop wasting people's time and not spread wrong ideas?right?
I REPEAT,I DID NOT MEAN ANY CONFUSION OR ANYTHING,I AM NO PROFESSIONAL,JUST A LEARNER.)

i was trying to learn this topic from youtube and google and learned that the transitive closure of a graph is the reachability matrix.I looked at this example on geeks for geeks and also some teachers on youtube saying "since A is obviously reachable from A we mark it 1"
my question is

1. does this mean the diagonal elements of transitive closure matrix always have to be 1, considering trivially that a vertex is always reachable to itself?
2. how does the formula of transitive closure capture this if yes?

3.does this mean we have to draw loops in the graph of transitive closure?i think that will be no,but anyways how does 1 draw the graph of transitive closure from reachability matrix.

i have also written this question on paper in a neat handwriting and attached it as screenshot to make it clear.( i can't really learn how formulae and graph are written here)

[this is the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLO2u.jpg)

[this is the second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4Qsd.jpg)

Comment: Try relation $\{(1,2),(3,4)\}$ on set $\{1,2,3,4\}.$

Comment: @coffeemath i think the transitive closure for the relation you wrote could be {(1,1),(1,2),(3,3),(3,4)} but could you answer how does that help my question in terms of graphs and reach-ability matrix?

Comment: please do consider the images,they point more clearly to what I'm asking,especially how does the formula of transitive closure would give entry 1 in the matrix for every (i,i) position.

Comment: What definition of transitive closure of relation R are you using?? The usual definition is: The intersection of all transitive relations which contain all pairs of R. With this definition the transitive closure of my example is itself, since it is already transitive.

Comment: i am using the deinition as I found on the first google search,that the transitive closure is the reachability matrix.And I found many teachers on YouTube while making the reachability matrix stating that since node (say 1) is trivially reachable from itself we mark it 1 in the reachability matrix.Now how is this captured in the formula A+(i,j)= A^1 + A^2 +... A^n-1.In particular the example I used in the image,there would not be any A(3,3)=1 from the formula.but it was showing 1 on the website geeks from geeks.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/transitive-closure-of-a-graph/

Comment: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~irani/w15-6B/BoardNotes/MatrixMultiplication.pdf

Comment: look at the last formula in the document

Comment: I am asking how would that formula capture that a node is trivially reachable from itself.

Comment: hmm,the only reasonable way for the formula to hold is that probably those teachers said it wrong and every vertex should not be considered trivially reachable to itself.that would make sense.but the only question then remains on my mind is why is the transitive closure matrix for that particular graph,in the geeksforgeeks website link i provided showing 1 for (i,j) = (3,3).

Comment: @coffeemath how is your relation transitive? there's an arrow from 1 to 2 and there's an arrow from 3 to 4 but that's it.there's no arrow which is pointing to some other element from the elements to which the arrows are pointing.it is definitely not transitive.you can not even show that its not not transitive,there is no chain of length two.

Comment: @coffeemath okay after some more researching i did find why your relation is transitive.It's because there is a to b  but no b to c so we cannot check for a to c hence can't say its not tansitive.But i would say except for your example this whole topic still confuses me.

Comment: here is the definition, right at the top of the wiki page for transitive closure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20transitive%20closure,minimal%20transitive%20superset%20of%20R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a disagreement on a choice of convention. If you want to count paths of length $0$, you'll need to add an $A^0$ term onto the beginning of your sum $A^1 + A^2 + A^3 + \cdots $. Each term $A^k$ counts the paths of exactly length $k$.

I find both possible conventions convincing: including paths of length $0$ makes sense if you're thinking about graphs and excluding them makes sense if you're thinking about relations.

Comment: okay that surely helps a bit.So are you saying that when considering graphs,and when making their reachability matrix,we have to consider A^0 in the formula.That is when making the reachability matrix of graphs the diagonals element must be 1.Also A^0 will just be a matrix with all diagonal elements 1 and everything else 0 right?

Comment: @RishabhNarula You're right about $A^0$ having 1's on diagonal and 0's elsewhere. Another way to say that is $A^0=I,$ the identity matrix.

Comment: @coffeemath so by that logic,the teachers were saying it right and there will always be 1s in the diagonal elements of reachability matrix of graphs right? thanks to both of you for some clarification on this topic by the way.